# What is the difference between `[]=` and `add` for HTTP::Server::Response#headers?

Tags: http-headers, crystal-lang

I looked at the source code for both `[]=` and `.add` when [adding/manipulating headers](http://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.24.1/http/headers). I'm still confused as to the reason why there are two ways to add/set headers. What are the differences between the two methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`[]=`](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/44ff90e25645e1208217ad79920d2124f63d14b2/src/http/headers.cr#L55) replaces all header key content with a new array of value

```
puts response.headers["Accept-Language"] # => ["de"]
response.headers["Accept-Language"] = "de-CH" # or ["de-CH"]
puts response.headers["Accept-Language"] # => ["de-CH"]
```

[.add](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/44ff90e25645e1208217ad79920d2124f63d14b2/src/http/headers.cr#L104) checks if header key exist and append the value:

```
puts response.headers["Accept-Language"] # => ["de"]
response.headers.add "Accept-Language", "de-CH"
puts response.headers["Accept-Language"] # => ["de", "de-CH"]
```